# Difference between functors $\text{Hom}_B(-,B)$ and $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(-,\mathbb C)$

Tags: modules, dual-spaces, functors, algebras, hom-functor

I am working with a commutative finite-dimensional $\mathbb C$-algebra $B$ and I am supposed to consider and prove a theorem about the hom-functors $$\text{Hom}_B(-,B)\quad\text{and}\quad \text{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(-,\mathbb C),$$ both of which are defined for $B\text{-mod}\rightarrow B\text{-mod}^{op}$. Here $B$-mod denotes the category of $B$-modules.

Can someone explain the difference between the two? I don't quite understand what the subscripts $B$ and $\mathbb C$ signify here and how the second one is even a functor that maps to $B$-mod$^{op}$.

Thanks!

Comment: The subscripts denote which type of module homomorphisms you are considering. Essentially, it tells you which scalars can be pulled outside of the function argument. So for example, $\text{Hom}_B(-, B)$ is the set of all $B$-module homomorphisms from some $B-\text{module}$ to $B$. The fact that the functor maps into $B-\text{mod}^{op}$ is to say that $\text{Hom}_B(-, B)$ is a contravariant functior (i.e., it reverses the direction of arrows).

Comment: Thanks @NicholasRoberts , that helps a lot!
However, I still don't understand what $\text{Hom}_\mathbb C(-, \mathbb C)$ is then. Could you explain this in terms of dual spaces maybe?
I don't know what you meant by 'type of module homomorphism'.

Comment: The functor $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(-,\mathbb C)$, takes a complex vector space to it's dual space. I believe it is a misprint that this functor goes from B-mod to B-mod^{op}.